# Strange behaviour while connecting two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have two classes `Profiles` and `Events` (one-to-many).

```cs
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int WhereProfileId { get; set; }
    public int WhoProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile WhereProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile WhoProfile { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public Profile()
    {
        EventsIAmWho = new List<Event>();
        EventsIAmWhere = new List<Event>();
    }
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> EventsIAmWho { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> EventsIAmWhere { get; set; }
}
```

**Config `onModelBuilder`:**

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
                    .HasMany(m => m.EventsIAmWho)
                    .WithOne(t => t.WhoProfile)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.WhoProfileId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
        .HasMany(m => m.EventsIAmWhere)
        .WithOne(t => t.WhereProfile)
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.WhereProfileId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

I need to get Event data from a specific Profile, i do simple like this:

`userProfile = _context.Profiles.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(e => e.EventsIAmWhere).FirstOrDefault();`

But got empty result (i put breakpoint on method return):

[image]

**So, after wasted many hours, i found strange behavior: if i add next line query request to `Events` table, `userProfile` variable got data!:**

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You missed "class" keyword when you define the Profile class. Could you correct it?

Comment: @Steven miss line while copy class data from ide, ty

Comment: Remove collection initialisation from constructor and everything will start working.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv after removing collection initialisation - `EventsIAmWhere` and `EventsIAmWho` is NULL

Comment: For HasForeignKey statements, could you try to use "t" instead of "m"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that both EF Core and EF6 packages were included in the project.
The migration was done using the EF Core namespace, and requests, by mistake, from the EF6 namespace.
After fixing all work as excepted